# Can I use INNER JOIN to replace WHERE?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, inner-join, where-clause

I have three tables. Employees, Projects (Many-To-Many) and EmployeesProject.

I want to retrieve the name of each employee and their respective projects.

I was trying to use this query:

```
SELECT Employee.name, Project.name 
FROM Employee, Project
INNER JOIN EmployeeProject ON Employee.empNo = EmployeeProject.empNo
INNER JOIN EmployeeProject ON Project.projectNo = EmployeeProject.projectNo;
```

Access was giving me a syntax error. Then I've tried this query and it worked:

```
SELECT Employee.name, Project.name 
FROM Employee, Project, EmployeeProject
WHERE Employee.empNo = EmployeeProject.empNo AND EmployeeProject.projectNo = Project.projectNo;
```

My question is; is that ok to use WHERE to link tables or there is a better way to do it, like INNER...

Regards

Comment: You must put "(" and ")" to your INNER JOINs if you are using MS ACCESS. It requires that. also use inner join in employee and project.

Comment: In case you are interested: a general comparison of [INNER JOIN vs WHERE](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6248640/422353) has been asked before.

Comment: Not according to [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208854(v=office.12).aspx) which shows examples of joins not `()` enclosed.

Comment: Ok then. Just stating from my experience in googling for that syntax before.

Comment: It's required when there is more than a single JOIN involved, because Access doesn't want to guess the order of resolution.

Comment: thank you for answering in detail. was too lazy to give the full answer :)

Comment: The built in **Query Designer** would write the syntax correctly for you ^_^

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - if you look at the VBA sample on that documentation page, you'll see that the query (which has multiple JOINS) does use parentheses around the JOIN pairs.

Comment: @ZevSpitz I know, I've seen it in the examples but what I meant yesterday is that I can't find where it is explicitly documented as necessary. Access has a tendency to build in many layers of superfluous `()` in SQL generated by its query builder, so it is difficult to know what is actually a syntactic requirement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using explicit `JOIN`s, you do not comma-separate tables in the `FROM` clause. The correct syntax for an explicit `JOIN` (preferred over the older implicit syntax using the `WHERE` clause) is:

```
SELECT
  /* Probably will need to give these aliases since the're both called name */
  Employee.name AS empname,
  Project.name AS projname 
FROM 
  Employee
  /* Employee joins through EmployeeProject */
  INNER JOIN EmployeeProject ON Employee.empNo = EmployeeProject.empNo
  /* ...into Project */
  INNER JOIN Project ON Project.projectNo = EmployeeProject.projectNo;
```

If Access is complaining, it may require `()` around the join clauses (though I cannot find documentation which specifies it)

```
FROM 
  (Employee
  INNER JOIN EmployeeProject ON Employee.empNo = EmployeeProject.empNo)
  INNER JOIN Project ON Project.projectNo = EmployeeProject.projectNo;
```

Comment: It is still giving me an error. It says syntax error (missing operator)

Comment: Try `()` around the first join pair

Comment: thats what I have stated. I cannot find any documentation regarding it but access requires it. :)

Comment: Now it is working. Thanks. Only one more question related. The result that I get shows all the employees and their related projects, good but if I want to show all the employees regardless if they are in a project. Thanks

Comment: Change to a `LEFT JOIN` between `Employee` and `EmployeeProject`.

Comment: Access is complying about that. If I do right join it accept ;however I don't get the expected result.

Comment: Complaining how? What error? `FROM (Employee LEFT JOIN EmployeeProject ON Employee.empNo = EmployeeProject.empNo) INNER JOIN Project ON Project.projectNo = EmployeeProject.projectNo` I would expect to work.

Comment: It says JOIN operation not supported. I fixed that changing both INNERs to LEFT and it worked.

Comment: @Camus Ok then.  Access is weird (evidenced also by the `()` requirement) - the mix of inner & left joins would work in other RDBMS.

Comment: Thanks again. I know access is a pain. I am just using it as academic purpose. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Michael It doesn't work because Access is for dummies, so it protects you against yourself. Your condition `((Employee Left join EmployeeProject) Inner join Project)` is formulated wrongly, because for the INNER JOIN to work, the EmployeeProject.projectNo must not be NULL from the first part.  Effectively, it's two INNER JOINS.

Comment: @Camus I answered your question with a tested query and explained Access nuances well before your later comments on this answer.

Comment: I am a dummy that's why I am studying. And I know projectNo will not be NULL because I set like that.

Answer (score 5):

1. Brackets **ARE** required, even in Access 2010, when you have more than 2 tables involved.
2. The order of tables in the JOIN is **important**.  You cannot jump from Employee -> Project (unrelated) through to EmployeeProject (joining on both)

### This works

```
SELECT Employee.name, Project.name 
FROM ((Employee
INNER JOIN EmployeeProject ON Employee.empNo = EmployeeProject.empNo)
INNER JOIN Project ON EmployeeProject.projectNo = Project.projectNo);
```

Note: You can drop the outer bracket between `FROM` and the final `;`, but safer practice to always include it.

You **can** nest joins - and preserve the ordering of the tables (Employee, Project, EmployeeProject) if you nest them like this:

```
SELECT Employee.name, Project.name 
FROM Employee
INNER JOIN (Project 
            INNER JOIN EmployeeProject 
              ON EmployeeProject.projectNo = Project.projectNo)
  ON Employee.empNo = EmployeeProject.empNo;
```

---

Using the explicit JOIN syntax is much more flexible, because you can now show employees even if they don't have any projects on - just by changing to **LEFT** joins.

```
SELECT Employee.name, Project.name 
FROM ((Employee
LEFT JOIN EmployeeProject ON Employee.empNo = EmployeeProject.empNo)
LEFT JOIN Project ON EmployeeProject.projectNo = Project.projectNo);
```

Note: In datasheet view and in forms, the columns produced are named "Employee.name" and "Project.name", so you don't explicitly have to alias them, although it could be useful.

Comment: +1 And hopefully the columns (fields) are not called by reserved words such as Name.