# Inner join differences

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, where-clause, crud

> I have a table1 (a,b,c) and table2(a,b,c)

What's the difference between

```
select * from table1 T1 inner join table2 T2 on
T1.a=T2.a and T1.b = t2.b and T1.c = T2.c
```

and

```
select * from table1 T1 inner Join table2 T2 on T1.a = T2.a  where 
T1.b= T2.b and T1.c = T2.C
```

Is is the same ?  and which one is  better?

Thanks

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248640/differance-between-inner-join-and-where?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248640/differance-between-inner-join-and-where?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

With inner joins there are no difference. It is only when you start using left/right joins, that you will see differences.

For LEFT JOINS, if you had

```
select  * 
from    table1 T1 LEFT join 
        table2 T2   on  T1.a=T2.a 
                    and T1.b = t2.b 
                    and T1.c = T2.c
```

It would include all rows fromo table1 and only rows from table2 where fields a,b and c matched.

If you had

```
select  * 
from    table1 T1 inner Join 
        table2 T2   on  T1.a = T2.a  
where   T1.b= T2.b 
and     T1.c = T2.C
```

This would include rows from table1 and those from table2 where a is equal, and then filter on b and c.

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2b1af/3)

I always find this visual representation usefull.

[SQL SERVER – Introduction to JOINs – Basic of JOINs](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/)

Comment: Performance wise, if the tables are indexes, should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

For your queries, this doesn't change anything.

**And in term of performance, your RDBMS is able to understand that it's the same.**

But considering you have more joins, this would change the **readability** of the query.

Example :

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM 
    table1 T1 
    INNER JOIN table2 T2 
        ON T1.a = T2.a 
        AND T1.b = T2.b 
        AND T1.c = T2.c
    LEFT JOIN table3 T3
        ON T3.x = T1.a
        AND T3.status = 1
WHERE
    T1.a > 100
```

You can understand faster which condition works with which table in `INNER/LEFT JOIN`